# Low trust SharePoint provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, provider-hosted-app

For learning purposes I am trying to create a low trust provider hosted app on my on prem SP2013 machine on a team site collection. I have created a new project with an MVC application template. When I press F5 the project runs and in the browser the application fails. The problems seems to be in the SharePoint context filter attribute. I get the can not redirect result. I have the same when using a webform provider hosted web.

I run the MVC app from IISExpress with anonymous auth. I have seen somewhere that I should disable anonymous. I trief that but didn't work.

What am I missing. Should the project created on the template not default work?

```
public class SharePointContextFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        Uri redirectUrl;
        switch (SharePointContextProvider.CheckRedirectionStatus(filterContext.HttpContext, out redirectUrl))
        {
            case RedirectionStatus.Ok:
                return;
            case RedirectionStatus.ShouldRedirect:
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl.AbsoluteUri);
                break;
            case RedirectionStatus.CanNotRedirect:
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this and follow step by step https://sptechbytes.blogspot.in/2013/08/sharepoint-2013-creating-sharepoint_30.html

Comment: I tried this before and I think then I could run from visual studio directly while pressing F5. Is there something changed in the TokenHelper?

Comment: I follow that website. Still the same issue.

Comment: This is the code that causes the error:

Comment: if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(httpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "POST"))
            {
                return RedirectionStatus.CanNotRedirect;
            }

Comment: This seemed relevant to your issue. Since you're dealing with HTTP requests and redirects, I can see security popping up along that chain. Abhyudaya Srinet's answer at: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d3d70290-520a-4975-848e-fd55e770b42f/sharepoint-2013-mvc-providerhosted-app-fails-to-pass-sharepointcontextfilter-on-httppost?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: There is no solution there. I can get it to work using high trust and using a certificate. Is low trust with on prem sp2013 even possible?